# Adding children to a group whose elements are a string and list

Tags: java

I have a list of book objects, each book has a name and a author

```
BooksObjects = {[Title 1, Author 1], [Title 2, Author 1] , [Title 3, Author 1], [Title 4, Author 2]...}
```

I would like to create a relationship which groups the authors to a list of books i.e

```
Groups = {[Author 1, {Title 1, Title 2, Title 3}, [Author 2, {Title 4, Title 5...} ...]
```

i.e `List<String, List<String>>` groups

How would i go about doing this?

I don't want to use a `HashMap` because it doesn't store the entry by order.

Comment: add some code pls. for exampleyour list with authors and titles.

Comment: Book object should be your key into hashmap and list of authors as its value. DO NOT forget to override equals and hashcode for Book.

Comment: @PrasadKharkar i don't want to use a hashmap because it doesn't store the entry by order

Comment: @AndroidEnthusiast If you want to store by order, you can use TreeMap.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to store entry by order then use

[LinkedHashMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html)

LinkedHashMap will iterate in the order in which the entries were put into the map